# How to upload image path and name to database - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, upload, insert

I know that this question has been asked several times, but all the other question I found are different from what I want.

I want to upload the filename and filepath to a table called 'factoryimages'.

What's the best way of doing this?

My controller function:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '';
    $config['max_height']  = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('members/header');
        $this->load->view('members/upload_form', $error);
        $this->load->view('members/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('members/header');
        $this->load->view('members/upload_success', $data);
        $this->load->view('members/footer');
    }
}
```

I tried this in my model, but it didn't work:

```
function insert_images()
{
    $insert_data = array(
    'filename' => $image_data['file_name'],
    'fullpath' => $image_data['full_path']
    );

    $this->db->insert('bedrijfimages', $insert_data);
}
```

My view:

```
<?php echo $error;?>
<br/>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" multiple="true" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

## Edit:

I get an server error but i can't see what it is.

My controller function:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '';
    $config['max_height']  = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->upload_model->insert_images($this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('members/header');
        $this->load->view('members/upload_form', $error);
        $this->load->view('members/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('members/header');
        $this->load->view('members/upload_success', $data);
        $this->load->view('members/footer');
    }
}
```

My model function:

```
function insert_images($data = array())
{
    $data = array(
    'filename' => $image_data['file_name'],
    'fullpath' => $image_data['full_path']
    );

    $this->db->insert('bedrijfimages', $data);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass this data to your insert as array  `$this->upload->data()`

At your Controller you must set when validation is done

```
else
{
    $this->MODELNAME->insert_images($this->upload->data());
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->view('members/header');
    $this->load->view('members/upload_success', $data);
    $this->load->view('members/footer');
}
```

And at your model:

```
function insert_images($image_data = array()){
      $data = array(
          'filename' => $image_data['file_name'],
          'fullpath' => $image_data['full_path']
      );
      $this->db->insert('bedrijfimages', $data);
}
```

You can check what information is inside this array at CI documentation page: [Codeigniter upload library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: i get an server error. please look at my code i just added to the question.

Comment: I updated my answer .. Notice that MODELNAME must be the name of your image model where you have that inserт_images function

Comment: I know. i already edited the MODELNAME but i had my modelname wrong in the model itself. i called it upload but it's called upload_model

Comment: hello i have to add image category ..  how can i add image category?

Comment: Don't use old answers for new question. Publish your question (with example of your code) and you will get help ..